# Two-dimensional acceleration structure

Tags: data-structures, geometry, 2d

I am writing a little game in which many (order 1000-10000) cars are driving around you and need to dodge each other smoothly. Their position can be represented by their 2D XY-coordinates.

Each frame, every car needs to ensure it doesn't bump into another one, which naively implemented would be an O(N^2) algorithm. What is the best 2D acceleration structure I can employ to make this more efficient?

To add some more context:

- Since cars can move anywhere, the structure needs to constantly keep track of all cars. So it needs to be quick to update (not O(N) for each car for example).
- Every car moves on every frame
- Cars are *not* allowed to hit any other car. They obviously have knowledge of their own size, and their current direction and speed. Their size is *none-zero* (cause you know, it's a car), and it needs this data in collision checks.
- I considered a regular grid with set-structure, which works, but each car still has to check its own cell and all its (8) neighbours, so I imagine there are still better ways.

Comment: Please try to give more information about your question: give us some code snippets, show us what you've tried and where it fails.

Comment: It's a higher-level question than that - I'm more curious about the kind of algorithm you'd employ than the specific implementation.

Comment: You may want to look up "quadtrees".

Comment: I don't know what a "regular grid with linked list" is, but the solution of having the car check each adjacent space is a good one. It reduces the problem from O(n^2) to O(n), which will be a huge win. Although I'm unsure how checking just the adjacent spaces will help if you want  cars to be moving at different speeds.

Answer (score 0):

So, you've to check if there is a collision. For there to be a collision if I understand your example, there have to be two cars in the same spot after the cars move.

I think we can use the concept of spot, or position, here. You could save the positions that at a given time have a car on them in a set (coordinates of a matrix, or whatever suits your problem best). When a car moves, delete it's position from the set and insert it's new one to the set.

Once we've this, you'll only have to check if the set contains a car's next position to know if there will be a collision or not, and in a HashSet consulting that is O(1). Apply that to your number of cars(n) and you'll do your collision management in O(n).

**Example for further clarification:**

You've this matrix of positions with cars on "O"s and empty spaces on "X"s. Meaning you'd have a car on position 1 and another one in position 8 if you number your positions from the top left corner.

```
O X X
X X X
X O X
```

This would imply you've a set of Integers with positions 1 and 8 on it. Now, an example to move one of the cars:

Car on position 1 moves to position 2: You check if position 2 is in the set[O(1)]. It isn't. You remove position 1 from the set[O(1)] and add position 2 to the set[O(1)], because now position 1 doesn't have a car on it but position 2 does.

Repeat for every car (n) => O(1) * O(n) = O(n).

Comment: If I understand correctly, each cell will have a set of cars/positions. But then every car update still needs to test against all other guys in the set, plus all neighbouring sets, to ascertain there is no collision, right? So I do not understand why this would be O(N)

Comment: Ill add an example.

Comment: Does it makes sense to you now? Basically, you only check against the position you want to go, because you know if there is or there isn't a car there by keeping the set.

Comment: I does make sense, thanks, and it's a very good start. For non-zero sized cars though, I think you'd find you might bump into neighbouring cars when e.g. you cross (say you move from (1, 1) to (2, 2) because there might be cars in e.g. (1,2) that are close enough to block, but you haven't checked.

Comment: Oh, thought cars could move diagonally. Well, that makes for 2 checks instead of 1 to move diagonally, its still under O(1).

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like a [quadtree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree). A quadtree is a 2D indexing scheme with O(log n) update (insert/remove) time.

The easiest possibility is to store rectangles (axis aligned bounding boxes) for each car. Then, each time before you reinsert a car at it's new position, you perform a window query (query for a rectangle) at the new position to see whether it overlaps with any other car. If you have the source code of the tree you can even implement a combined operation updateAnCheck() that detects collisionas and updates in a single call. (I assume that the structure is updated often enough that old and new position overlap, so that collisions are more or less reliably detected, other wise cars could 'teleport' through one another if they are fast enough).

Complexity:

- Update: O(log n) per car
- Query: O(log n) per car
- Space: About O(log n) per car

Total computational complexity: detecting all collisions for n car: O(n * 2 * log n) = O(n log n)
Total space complexity: about O(n * log n)

There are many open source implementations for quadtrees available, if you are using Java, you may want to check out [mine](https://github.com/tzaeschke/tinspin-indexes).